# What is the difference between creating an image from a disk and creating an image from a snapshot in GCP?

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, snapshot

In Google Cloud Platform, what is the difference between creating an image from a disk and taking a snapshot of the disk and then creating the image from the snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing, you create an image. The image from disk is the immediate copy of active data. Image from snapshot can refer older data, depending on the age of the snapshot.

So, if you create a snapshot and immediately create an image on the snapshot (and you don't care to keep a snapshot ), the snapshot step is useless. It's only a question of temporality.